# How does jnz work in MSP430 assembly?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, msp430

I'm running the following code:

```
448a:  bf90 263e 0000 cmp   #0x3e26, 0x0(r15)
4490:  0d20           jnz   $+0x1c
```

With an r15 value of:

```
r15 = 439c
```

While the memory looks like:

```
4390:   6045 0200 9c43 6400 8844 5044 3e26 0000
```

Note that at memory locations `439c` and `439d` the values `3e` and `26` is being stored (respectively). Thus, I expect the `Zero` flag to be activated once command `448a` is executed, however this is not happening.

So my question is, why is it that the `Zero` flag is not being activated despite the fact that two equal values (`3e26`) are being compared?

Comment: MSP430 is little endian, so your bytes in memory actually represent `0x263e` not `0x3e26` hence not equal.

Comment: @Jester thanks, that did it